# What is the default metrics for Keras model.compile()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have created Sequential model and compile it with:

`model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-5, momentum=0.9))`

It converges fast but I do not know what metrics is used as default. The documentation does not explain it.

Does anyone know what is the default metric?

Answer (score 0):

There will be no additional metrics with that statement. Fitting will show you  the loss function.

[Github Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L479)

Comment: Thanks but I probably do not have enough knowledge to understand this completely.